# External Class for Android Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I'm learning Android Development and started creating an app which has about 20 dialog (yes, no button).
I planned to create a class which will return true or false upon yes/no press. Then class is here

```
public class CustomDialog{
Boolean Resp;

public Boolean Confirm(Activity act, String Title, String ConfirmText,
        String CancelBtn, String OkBtn) {
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
    dialog.setTitle(Title);
    dialog.setMessage(ConfirmText);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, OkBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                     Resp = true;
                }
            });
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, CancelBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                    Resp = false;
                }
            });

    dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    dialog.show();
    if (Resp == null){
        Resp = false;
    }
    return Resp;
}
}
```

Now when I'm calling this from main activity, within a button click listener, app is crushing.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Toast){
        CustomDialog tans = new CustomDialog();
        boolean tan = tans.Confirm(MainActivity.this, "Message Title", "Message Text Goes Here", "No", "Yes");
        if (tan){
            Toast.makeText(this, "wow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I need your advice to fix.

**EDIT:** I've updated my code, app isn't crushing now but no toast while pressing Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of **this** to **MainActivity.this** as follow:

```
 Boolean tan = tans.Confirm(MainActivity.this, "Confirmation", "Are you sure?", "No", "Yes");
```

Also one more thing your Boolean tan variable value is **null** as **Resp** variable is not initialized during **tans.Confirm** method is called. **Resp** value is changed only after user click Yes or No button.

[[image]android](/questions/tagged/android)